# NodeJS: URL friendly show blank pages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, routes, react-router

I'm developing a web page with Node.js and React.js and right now my site has these urls:

```
/liga-femenina-1
/liga-femenina-1/equipos
/liga-femenina-1/resultados
/liga-femenina-1/estadisticas
/liga-femenina-1/buscador
/liga-femenina-2
/liga-femenina-2/equipos
/liga-femenina-2/resultados
/liga-femenina-2/estadisticas
/liga-femenina-2/buscador
```

To detect these url's I have defined this regular expression:

```
\/liga-femenina-(1|2)\/?\w*
```

This regular expression detects correctly all the url's. You can check it here:

[image]

I use this regular expression to detect all these url's in my file routes.js with this code:

```
import {Router} from "express";
import path from "path";

const router = Router();
router.get(/\/liga-femenina-(1|2)\/?\w*/, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../../dist/index.html"));
});
```

With these code, If I access directly to url's like http://localhost:4000/liga-femenina-1 or http://localhost:4000/liga-femenina-2 works fine. But If I try to access to these other url's:

```
/liga-femenina-1/equipos
/liga-femenina-1/resultados
/liga-femenina-1/estadisticas
/liga-femenina-1/buscador
/liga-femenina-2/equipos
/liga-femenina-2/resultados
/liga-femenina-2/estadisticas
/liga-femenina-2/buscador
```

Then, the web page is not rendered. The web page appears in blank.

How can I detect all the urls? What am I doing wrong?

**Edit I:**

I have checked which request receive the server when the page is rendered and when is not rendered. For example, If I request this url: http://localhost:4000/liga-femenina-1 the page is rendered and in the server we've got:

```
GET /liga-femenina-1 200 1.135 ms - 642
GET /assets/js/bundle.js 304 0.549 ms - -
```

But If I request this url: http://localhost:4000/liga-femenina-1/equipos, the page is not rendered and in the server we've got:

```
GET /liga-femenina-1/equipos 200 0.950 ms - 642
**GET /liga-femenina-1/assets/js/bundle.js 404 0.607 ms - 174**
```

In the first case, when the server is going to seek the bundle.js file, it do it from /assets/js/bundle.js and render the web page. But in the second case, the server is going to seek the bundle.js file in the directory **/liga-femenina-1**/assets/js/bundle.js. And this directory doesn't exists.

Therefore, why in the first case the server access correctly to the file and in the second case doesn't do it correctly?

Therefore, why in the first case the server access correctly to the file and in the second case doesn't do it correctly?